# How to get variabels from Class x and set them at Class y

Tags: c#, class

For school im makeing a online shop application. i have 2 listboxes, one with products and one that is like a shopping cart:

[image]

Now i have the following classes:

```
public class Artikel
{
    // instantie variabelen
    private string artikelnaam;
    private string categorie;
    private double prijs;

    // properties
    public string Artikelnaam { get; }
    public string Categorie { get; }
    public double Prijs { get; }

    // constructor
    public Artikel(string artikelnaam, string categorie, double prijs)
    {
        this.artikelnaam = artikelnaam;
        this.categorie = categorie;
        this.prijs = prijs;
    }
    // ToString methode
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return artikelnaam + "\t" + categorie + "\t" + prijs;
    }
}
```

and the shopping cart class:

```
class WinkelwagenObject
{
    // instantie variabelen
    private string artikelnaam;
    private string categorie;
    private int aantal;
    private double prijs;
    private double subtotaal;

    // properties
   public string Artikelnaam { get; }
    public string Categorie { get; }
    public int Aantal { get; set; }
    public double Prijs { get; }
    public double Subtotaal { get; }


    // constructor
    public WinkelwagenObject(string artikelnaam, string categorie, int aantal, double prijs, double subtotaal)
    {
        this.artikelnaam = artikelnaam;
        this.categorie = categorie;
        this.aantal = aantal;
        this.prijs = prijs;
        this.subtotaal = subtotaal;
    }

    // ToString methode
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return artikelnaam + "\t" + categorie + "\t" + aantal + "\t" + prijs + "\t" + subtotaal;
    }
```

Now how do i selected a product in the lb of the products and send it too the shopping cart with the button "toevoegen"

Comment: Your cart should have some collection of products and don't repeat the name, category and price of them.

Comment: In your `WinkelwagenObject` there should be a `List<Artikel>` to store your collection

Comment: Note that there **shouldn't** be duplication of informations. What belongs to an `Artikel` should stay in `Artikel`. [DRY !](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Comment: Why are you using fields and auto-implemented properties at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You could make an Add-Method to the your Cart-Class that recieves an Artikel-Object and puts it into an Artikel-Collection like this:

```
    public List<Artikel> ArtikelList { get; private set; }

    public void Add(Artikel artikel)
    {
        if (ArtikelList == null)
            ArtikelList = new List<Artikel>();

        ArtikelList.Add(artikel);
    }
```

Comment: You can now use your add method like this: `public WinkelWagenObject cart = new WinkelWagenObject();

            public Artikel newArtikel = newArtikel();

            cart.Add(newArtikel);`

So you will have an instance of your cart object. Then you can just call the Add method of it with giving the Artikel object to add as parameter.